# Multiple If statements and highlighting if no if statements are matched

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple if statements that need to be done simultaneously or else most of the spreadsheet will be highlighted. There are 5 columns that have information and account numbers that need to match, and dates of service need to be greater than or equal to the request date. The code I have highlights the whole spreadsheet (the dates are converted to integers in general format and will be converted back to dates after the calculation is made as I have noticed vba is more difficult with dates) I cannot post the workbook as the information is sensitive but I could make a sample workbook if one is desired.

```
Sub check_for_copies()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For j = 2 To 1000

    For i = 2 To 10000

        If Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 8).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then

        'do nothing

        ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then

        'do nothing

        ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 10).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then

        'do nothing

        ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 11).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then

        'do nothing

        ElseIf Sheets("C").Cells(j, 7).Value <= Sheets("B").Cells(i, 12).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 12).Value = Sheets("B").Cells(i, 16).Value Then

        'do nothing

        Else

        Sheets("C").Rows(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: In the code, I'm trying to test 3 things:
the initial test of <= makes sure the date of the appointment was after or on the date of the request, and compares values in the request sheet with the master list of appointments.
The second test makes sure the account numbers match
the third test checks a code versus the code of the appointment.

Is there a way to link all the if statements together so it will highlight the cells unless theres an appointment on the master sheet B for each code? The codes are listed in H-M on Sheet C and they are the cause of the issue with the code.

Comment: I found a work around but I'm not sure how to implement it into my code. For the first if test, I need to add And Sheets("C").Cells(j, 8).Value = CR15 but for some reason the code is not working at all, with Value or Value2. I think it has something to do with it being alphanumeric. Using this I would be able to update the remaining if loops.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Unless CR15 is a variable name it should be in quotes.

Comment: It worked, I just needed to add the quotes! Thank you so much!

Comment: How would I go about implementing ('do nothing) as code?

Comment: Your code should work as it is - if you step through you should see. You could I suppose shorten your If statement but not sure it's worth the bother.

Comment: I'm running into another issue - running the code crashes excel. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just noticed the size of your loops. You're running through 10m iterations. Do you really need that many? Given that your first two statements don't vary you could try combining them into one. Try the usual tips for speeding up code.